# How to add log when an Java Spring application has successfully started?

Tags: java, spring, logging

I have a requirement to add some logging to a Java Spring application to note that the application has ben restarted and so we can create notifications and hooks from its presence. Can anyone suggest the best way of doing this? All the resources I can find talk about Java Bean life cycle rather than the Application Lifecycle.

Comment: You mean the server has restarted ?

Comment: No, not the server, but the Java application running on the server

Answer (score 1):

You probably would be interested to look into [Event Handling in Spring.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/event_handling_in_spring.htm)
You have to catch **ContextStartedEvent**

> This event is published when the ApplicationContext is started using
>   the start() method on the ConfigurableApplicationContext interface.
>   You can poll your database or you can re/start any stopped application
>   after receiving this event.

```
public class CStartEventHandler 
   implements ApplicationListener<ContextStartedEvent>{

   public void onApplicationEvent(ContextStartedEvent event) {
      System.out.println("ContextStartedEvent Received");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into ApplicationListener and particularly;

```
ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>
```

You can implement this in with the following steps:

- 1. Create a class that implements ApplicationListener as such:

`public class RestartNotifier implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        log.info("*** Application initialised ***");
    }
}`

- 2. Add the following bean configuration to your ApplicationContext

`<bean id="applicationInitialised" class="path.RestartNotifier"/>`

That should do the trick..